# Would if be possible and reasonably to add a 3d model for a character in an isometric game built in actionscript?

Tags: actionscript, model, 3d, character, isometric

I am developing an isometric game but I want the user to be able to see all sides of their character. Is it possible to import a 3d model into an actionscript (flash)? Also is this a good idea? Or should I stick with the basic 2d sprite idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answers: Yes. Probably not. Probably. :-)

There are programs which convert a 3D model into a swf animation of the model rotating [but you could create this yourself].

And libraries which allow you to directly import collada files [eg. PaperVision]

Isometric projection is a 2D view of a 3D world, so if you are going to import a 3D character, you will probably want to put them into a 3D world.

eg. If the character is rotated 10% and you want them to walk straight ahead, where would they walk on the isometric grid?

Adding that extra dimension will increase the complexity of your project.

Depending on what you want to achieve you could get away with only showing the character from 4 different sides.

Comment: additionally, I have recently come accross a library called as3isolib http://code.google.com/p/as3isolib/ , although I haven't had the chance to use it yet, it doesn look interesting and could save you some ground work.

Comment: I love that library, I am currently using it. I just wondered if the 3d model was a good thing to do. I'm trying to build a beautiful interface, not like any ordinary isometric game, but with shading and such. Maybe this goes into context of a 2.5d game?

Comment: I'd be really interested to see what you come up with... and it might be worth creating a blog if you are serious about it to show off what you are doing, generate interest, get early feedback and keep you motivated. here's another random link which has a whole wealth of knowledge... http://fbindie.posterous.com/

Comment: Thank you for the feedback! I will keep you updated if you like?